# How to persist change to mongo in shell?

Tags: mongodb

I've pulled up a document in the mongo shell

```
   car = db.cars.findOne();

  ...make some changes... 

   car = db.cars.findOne();

   results for same document as if no changes had been made it
```

There's no save method on a cursor in mongodb. What can I do to persist changes in the shell?

Update. The car document (the first one that's pulled up) has an array of previousdrivers. I have to remove one of the elements and save the doc with it removed.

```
"previousdrivers" : [
    {
        "year" : "2011",
        "name" : Mr. Zed"
    },
    {
        "year" : "2012",
        "name" : "Mr. Bean"
    },
    {
        "year" : "2013",
        "name" : "Mr. Smith"
    }

]
```

Comment: You have to detail what changes you're making that you want to be persisted, as ideally you wouldn't be called save on a cursor, but on a document. Otherwise using update.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I updated the OP with more detail. Can you provide an example answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findOne()` method doesn't return a cursor but a document. You can use any javascript method to manipulate the array. When done, you can call `save()` for that document. Example

```
> db.cars.save({make : "ford", gears : [1,2,3,4,5]})
> var doc = db.cars.findOne()
> doc.gears.pop()
5
> db.cars.save(doc)
> db.cars.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52239e729a713e4fbc425ed1"),
    "make" : "ford",
    "gears" : [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Mongodb shell, you need to use the [methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-collection/) on the collection object to update a document.

For example, if you first:

```
car = db.cars.findOne();
```

Then, modify the `car` instance, you can just use the `save` method to update the single document ([save documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save)).

```
db.cars.save(car);
```

That will update the single document in the `cars` collection.

For more advanced usage, you might consider using one of the [Array operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) which can directly manipulate an array as part of an `update`.